# Select query, need extra where clause?

Tags: sql

I have a query that returns a list of song names for the selected people when they both know that song and the status is complete.

Is there a way to only show the songs where the status is complete, when all Instruments are not put as 'N/A'?

For example, suppose the table content is the following one.

```
    BandieName SongName    Instrument  Status
    Holly      Wipeout     Bells       Complete
    Holly      Centenial   N/A         Complete
    Charlotte  Wipeout     Symbols     Complete
    Charlotte  Centenial   N/A         Complete
```

if I select *Holly* and *Charlotte* from the list, and run the query, it will list *Wipeout* and *Centenial*, as they both have those songs as status complete; however, I do not want it to show *Centenial* because all of the selected people for that song have instrument as *N/A*.

If the content was as below, and I selected the three of them, I would want it to show all the  three songs, as not all of the instruments listed for that song is *N/A*.

```
    BandieName SongName    Instrument  Status
    Holly      Wipeout     Bells       Complete
    Holly      Centenial   N/A         Complete
    Charlotte  Wipeout     Symbols     Complete
    Charlotte  Centenial   N/A         Complete
    Ryan       Wipeout     Drum        Complete
    Ryan       Centenial   Drum        Complete
```

My code so far is the following one.

```
Protected Sub btnGetPlaylist_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGetPlaylist.Click

    Dim conn As SqlConnection = Nothing
    Try
        Dim connString As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BandDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
        conn = New SqlConnection(connString)

        Dim sqlBandies As String

        Dim item As ListItem
        For Each item In ListBoxBandies.Items
            If item.Selected Then

                Dim selectedBandies As String = item.Text
                sqlBandies &= "'" & item.Text & "', "

            End If
        Next

        Dim amountSelected As String = ListBoxBandies.Items.Count.ToString


        Dim query As String = "select SongName from Learning where BandieName in (" + sqlBandies + " '') AND Status = 'Complete' group by SongName having count(distinct BandieName) = " + ListBoxBandies.GetSelectedIndices.Length.ToString

        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query, conn)

        conn.Open()
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
        dt.Load(dr)
        GridViewPlaylist.DataSource = dt
        GridViewPlaylist.DataBind()


    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: So let me clarify your goal: You want song names connected to ALL of the selected BandieNames, all have status completed, and AT LEAST ONE has some instrument (Not N/A) selected?

Comment: yea that is it, at the moment i can get the songnames connected to all the selected Bandienames where the status is complete, but want those songnames where the status is complete and atleast one of the instruments is not N/A

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean find all the songs where all specified names have the song and as status complete and at least one of them (but not necessarily all) has a non "N/A" value as the instrument then you can do one of several approaches eg:

```
select s.SongName  
from Learning s  
  left outer join Learning specInstrument on specInstrument.SongName = s.SongName and specInstrument.BandieName = s.BandieName and specInstrument.Instrument <> 'N/A'  
where s.BandieName in ('Holly', 'Charlotte')  
  and s.Status = 'Complete'  
having count (distinct s.BandieName) = 2  
and count(specInstrument.SongName) > 0
```

Or find all matching songs that have a populated instrument for one of the matching names and link to that:

```
select s.SongName  
from Learning s   
inner join (select SongName from Learning where status = 'Complete' and BandieName in ('Holly', 'Charlotte') and instrument <> 'N/A') hasInstr on hasInstr.SongName = s.SongName  
where s.BandieName in ('Holly','Charlotte')  
and status = 'Complete'  
group by s.SongName  
having count(distinct s.BandieName) = 2
```

Obviously where you've built the list of names to check and the corresponding count of names I've substituted values but this shows the principle.

Comment: what is the s representing in this? also specInstrument? 
Thanks

Comment: They're just aliases for the table - basically (although s is a bit short :-) ) they're about referring to the table in a meaningful fashion. S being the song list, specInstrument a specified instrument having been found. It's just useful (especially when using the same table more than once in a query) to be explicit about what a table represents in a query

Comment: Great! Note if you could avoid building the SQL dynamically/check what's in the names as you build the list you'd be less vulnerable to SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
     BandName
     , SongName
     , Instrument
     , Status
FROM Learning  as l1
INNER JOIN (
              Select
                   BandName
                   , SongName
              FROM Learning
              WHERE Instrument <> 'N/A' AND Status = 'Complete'
            ) AS l2
  ON l1.BandName = l2.BandName AND l1.SongName = l2.SongName
```

Comment: I don't think this is at all what the original poster asked... You are not restricting by BandieName, you are returning songs which may have statuses other than 'Complete', etc.

Comment: The status is restricted to complete by the sub select.  After reading the OPs comments, I will edit to make it more like what they want.

Comment: The status needed to be complete on all Bandies, not just the one (or many) which have an instrument selected.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient search, but it should work. I can try and think of a more efficient solution a little later.

```
SELECT DISTINCT SongName
FROM Learning l1
WHERE 
    EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM Learning l2
        WHERE l1.BandieName = '<First selected BandieName>'
            AND l1.SongName = l2.SongName
            AND l2.Status = 'Complete')
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM Learning l3
        WHERE l1.BandieName = '<Second selected BandieName>'
            AND l1.SongName = l3.SongName
            AND l3.Status = 'Complete')
    -- Repeat these for however many people are selected.
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM Learning lInstrument
        WHERE NOT lInstrument = 'N/A'
            AND l1.SongName  = lInstrument.SongName
            AND BandieName IN (<BandieName list>)
            AND lInstrument.Status = 'Complete')
```

Comment: How would i integrate this with my current code? where the Names are from the list box? and it has the 'count' and 'having' clause in?
Thanks

Comment: In the section where you loop through the selected bandies, you build two strings with one being the list used in the last exists clause, and the second being the repeated exists clauses (the first two in my sample). Then when you build your sql, you write the SELECT clause, the FROM clause, include the repeated Exists clauses, and add in the last EXISTS clause with the list you built.

Answer (score 0):

Your Query would be:

```
WITH LearningCTE AS
(   SELECT  *
    FROM    Learning
    WHERE   BandieName IN ('Holly', 'Charlotte', 'Ryan')
    AND     Status = 'Complete'
)
SELECT  *
FROM    LearningCTE a
WHERE   EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    LearningCTE b
            WHERE   a.SongName = b.SongName
            AND     Instrument != 'N/A'
        )
```

If your using SQL Server 2008 I'd reccomend using a table parameter rather than dynamically building your SQL in VB.NET, it removes any risk of SQL Injection. You need to do something like the following:

```
CREATE TYPE NameList AS TABLE (Name VARCHAR(50))
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetPlayList (@Names NameList)
AS
BEGIN
    WITH LearningCTE AS
    (   SELECT  l.*
        FROM    Learning l
                INNER JOIN @Names
                    ON BandieName = Name
        WHERE   Status = 'Complete'
    )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    LearningCTE a
    WHERE   EXISTS
            (   SELECT  1
                FROM    LearningCTE b
                WHERE   a.SongName = b.SongName
                AND     Instrument != 'N/A'
            )
END
```

Then you can use VB code akin to this to pass the parameters

```
Protected Sub btnGetPlaylist_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGetPlaylist.Click
        Dim conn As SqlConnection = Nothing
        Try
            Dim connString As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BandDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
            conn = New SqlConnection(connString)

            Dim NameTable As New DataTable()
            NameTable.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))

            For Each item As ListItem In ListBoxBandies.Items
                If item.Selected Then
                    Dim newRow As DataRow = NameTable.NewRow()
                    newRow(0) = item.Text
                    NameTable.Rows.Add(newRow)
                End If
            Next

            Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("dbo.GetPlayList", conn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Names", NameTable))
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                conn.Open()
                Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
                    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                    dt.Load(dr)
                    GridViewPlaylist.DataSource = dt
                    GridViewPlaylist.DataBind()
                End Using
            End Using
        Finally
            conn.Close()
        End Try

    End Sub
```

I've added a couple of 'using's to some of your disposable elements, but other than that I've just tried to reuse your code.

Comment: I don't think your first query fills the requirements, as it doesn't check that all Bandies are complete. It just checks that at least one Bandie is complete and has an instrument set.